# How to connect kusto database with C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-explorer, kql

WithAadUserPromptAuthentication mising so i cant use sample code which is provided by Microsoft documentation?
That Is
:

```
var serviceUri = "Service URI, typically of the form https://cluster.region.kusto.windows.net";
var authority = "contoso.com"; // Or the AAD tenant GUID: "..."

// Recommended syntax
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri)
  .WithAadUserPromptAuthentication(authority);

// Legacy syntax
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri)
{
    FederatedSecurity = true,
    InitialCatalog = "NetDefaultDB",
    Authority = authority,
};

// Equivalent Kusto connection string: $"Data Source={serviceUri};Database=NetDefaultDB;Fed=True;Authority Id={authority}"
```

Is there is any new solution instead of WithAadUserPromptAuthentication methode?

Comment: Hi, Nikita Bhopale. Is my reply helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data.NETStandard is deprecated and is no longer maintained.
Please use Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data package (.Net framework and .Net Core flavors).

This method is not available with .Net Core, only with the .Net framework package due to the authentication library used (ADAL).
The workaround you can use with .Net Core is to trigger username/password authentication by setting the following properties manually on your KustoConnectionStringBuilder instance: FederatedSecurity, UserID, Password, Authority.

We are planning to release a new version of the package built with the next gen authentication library (MSAL) that will expose this method (interactive user auth) on all platforms.

Comment: Published https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data/9.0.1-preview based on MSAL with support for interactive AuthN on Net Core

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid `WithAadUserPromptAuthentication` has moved from `KustoConnectionStringBuilder`. Both Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data.NETStandard(6.1.8) and Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data(8.1.5) don't contain this method.

[image]
[image]

You could try this example using ApplicationClientId and ApplicationKey. Or other methods from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/kusto#aad-based-authentication-examples).

```
var serviceUri = "Service URI, typically of the form https://cluster.region.kusto.windows.net";
var authority = "contoso.com"; // Or the AAD tenant GUID: "..."
var applicationClientId = <ApplicationClientId>;
var applicationKey = <ApplicationKey>;

// Recommended syntax
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri)
    .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(applicationClientId, applicationKey, authority);

// Legacy syntax
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri)
{
    FederatedSecurity = true,
    InitialCatalog = "NetDefaultDB",
    ApplicationClientId = applicationClientId,
    ApplicationKey = applicationKey,
    Authority = authority,
};

// Equivalent Kusto connection string: $"Data Source={serviceUri};Database=NetDefaultDB;Fed=True;AppClientId={applicationClientId};AppKey={applicationKey};Authority Id={authority}"
```

Comment: Thank You @pamela-peng. But what is ApplicationClientId  and applicationKey?   where to get that?

Comment: Hi, @NikitaBhopale. `ApplicationClientId` is the application id of your application in AAD. `ApplicationKey` is the value of client secret. You could find them in the portal, navigate to Azure Active Directory-> App registrations-> your app-> Overview- `Application (client) ID` and Certificates & secrets- `Client secrets`.